# Apk Deployment Error

Tags: android, upload, apk, google-play, publishing

I'm getting the error when trying to upload my apk file:

'dump failed because no androidmanifest.xml found'

Does the package name in the AndroidManifest have to be the same as the deployed apk name? Also, does the apk name have to be in the form: com.xxxx.xxxx? Or should, say, TestPro.apk be ok?

Regards...Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Use `Winzip` or zip reader to open your APK file to check whether `AndroidManifest.xml` exists inside your package.

Answer (score 0):

After having the exact same problem (and losing about 4 hours of my life deleting and repasting my entire project...), I finally gave up and contacted Google and this was their answer:

> Thank you for your note. Please try these troubleshooting steps and
>   let us know if one of them resolves your problem:
>
> - Try to upload the app in the new version of the Developer Console (or the old version if you've already tried the new one).
> - Wait for your developer account fee to process (you will no longer see the 'Your registration is being processed...' banner in your
>     Google Play Developer Console).
> - Verify that your manifest file conforms to Android coding standards (see the following help articles:
>     http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html
>     and http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html).

All of the above did not work for me.

I asked someone about this issue and here was the answer that worked for me:

I had copied and pasted my project's .apk file onto my desktop and worked from there.

WHAT I SHOULD HAVE DONE: (and then did, and it worked)

Export the project properly from Eclipse as an android application, and then follow the procedure (key, password and all). I was then able to successfully continue.

Also, although I think that you can have your package name be whatever you want, it is my understanding that the accepted convention is to have it in the: com.XXX.XXX.projectName format.