# Cant upload APK, failed because no AndroidManifest.xml found

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, upload, apk

I have created my app on google play, when I got to sumbit the APK I get this error:

```
Upload failed

Your APK cannot be analyzed using 'aapt dump badging'. Error output:

Failed to run aapt dump badging:
ERROR: dump failed because no AndroidManifest.xml found
```

I clearly have a AndroidManifest.xml file in my project, I also have compressed my .apk to .zip too, I'm clueless to whats wrong.

Comment: maybe related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686427/the-file-is-invaliderrordump-failed-because-no-androidmanifest-xml-found give a look

Comment: I think you are trying to upload complete project from eclipse workspace..! Have you gone through [Signing Your Apps](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) ? if you are going to upload your .apk..

Comment: i have exactly the same problem. with android bundle eclipse and sample project!! so there's no error in the manifest or the code

Comment: I answered this here: [someone else's question][1]

Hope that helps!

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14497101/1927942

Answer (score 0):

There are few steps before going to upload .apk on Play store

1.Generate private key using

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore
-alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

2.Compile application in release mode: Right click on project then chose **Android Tools** then **Export Unsigned Application Package** give the location where you want to save the .apk. Here after successful saving, eclipse alert you about What next to do?

3.Now sign your application with private key generated in step first

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore
your_app_name.apk alias_name
```

in this step `jarsigner` may throw the error if your my-release-key.kestore and your_app_name.apk are not at same location.

4.align your package using `zipalign` tool

```
zipalign -v 4 your_project_name-unaligned.apk your_project_name.apk
```

[very clearly explained at developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Rahul is right, I am also struggling with all the landmines left behind by google, but I managed to complete step 3 thanks to his insight.

I must add that JDK7 users must change the encryption algorithms and key size with the jarsigner:

1)
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 –keystore mykeystore myApp.apk mykey

2)
keytool -genkey -alias mykeystore -keyalg RSA -keysize 1024  -sigalg MD5withRSA -keystore mykey –validity 36500